# fetch api change POST request to GET request when send it to the server

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch

[image]

I experienced very weird bug during using `fetch` API. As the picture above shows, the `method` property of `Request` is `POST`, but `fetch` send the request using `GET` method.

Also, among three macbooks, two macbooks(one Catalina beta, one Mojave) experienced the same bug, but one macbook(Mojave) did not. The last one just works perfectly.

All three machines used same Wifi network and same version of Chrome.

Where can I start to solve this bug? Any kind of suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Code where you get error ?

Comment: Sorry, completely restart VSCode and remove cache solve the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the log message closely, it says:

> ```
> redirected: true
> ```

So you **are** making a POST request, but the server responds with a redirect response so the browser follows the redirect and makes a GET request to the new URL. This is handled transparently by the `fetch` API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your two urls, it is different

[not same url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2228l.png)